# type conversion from Uint8Array to Float32

Tags: javascript

I have Uint8Array which is point data and i need to convert that to Float32Array

When i do

```
let x = UINT8ARRAY that i have of [204, 69, 200, 191, ....... ]
let y = Float32Array.from(x)
```

i get wrong value which i believe is because it does no conversion but only convert x to y but of 32 bit value

Then i tried this

```
let x = UINT8ARRAY that i have
let y = new Float32Array(x.buffer)
```

I get Float32Array of -1.56

This works fine for array while testing might be because this is small length but when i use this in my project which has Uint8Array of length 3 millions, it throws error saying

***byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4***

when i `console.log( myUint8Array, myUint8Array.buffer)`

It console me

```
Uint8Array(3046496) ArrayBuffer(3046777)
```

Comment: `3046496` & `3046777`,  well `3046777` is not a multiple of 4, but why the difference does seem odd, what browser are you using or were are you getting this buffer from?.  If I do -> `const c = new Uint8Array(3046496); console.log(c, c.buffer)` in Chrome, I'm getting -> `Uint8Array(3046496) & ArrayBuffer(3046496)`

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: I am getting this data from ROS and this data is point cloud data with each 32 bytes is one point data.

Answer (score 0):

> The `uint8Array.length` is 3046496 whereas the `arrayBuffer.length` is 3046777

Then you will need to take the offset and length of the `Uint8Array` into account, which is only a **view** on a part of the buffer. Use

```
const y = new Float32Array(x.buffer, x.byteOffset, x.byteLength / Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
```

(or choose your own length, if the `Uint8Array` is not actually the range that you want)

> I am getting this data from ROS

Then you probably should not be using a `Float32Array` anyway, whose endianness depends on the system architecture, but rather should use a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) and call the [`getFloat32` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getFloat32) with the endianness of your ROS for each index.

Comment: Thank you so much for this knowledge, one thing that i tried first was using DataView and using getFloat32 but it turned out it only gives one float number at a time and i need to convert this data around 30 times a second and visualize this so i thought it wont be efficient enough to do it for each float number, do you suggest any different way?

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it's efficient or not when it doesn't work. Focus on correctness first. Did you actually try it, was it too slow?