# not able to convert Uint8 to FLoat32 Array in JS

Tags: javascript, point-cloud-library

I have pointData which is Uint8Array of point data with the structure of each point is 20 bytes and x, y, z have offset of 0, 4, 8 and intensity is at offset of 16 and all are of 4 bytes.

The data is stored in Uint8Array with each point is in stride. I don't know if this will add value or not but wanted to give context.

The data is in Uint8Array and vertex attribute in shader does not accept Uint8 so i need to convert this to Float32 typed array.

When i do,

```
if (pointData.byteLength > 0) {
    console.log(pointData);
    const PointData_2 = new Float32Array(pointData.buffer);
}
```

I get this console log and error:

[image]

can anyone please help me figure out what is wrong and how can i do this.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the length of your buffer is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: Btw, have you still not considered [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76624535/1048572)?

Comment: @Barmar https://stackoverflow.com/q/34669537 is not an appropriate duplicate, `Float32Array.from` does not re-interpret the bytes in the buffer but rather creates a 32-bit float from each 8-bit int

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(pointData.byteLength)` in your script.

Comment: I was just able to do this with a 4 byte array that I created by hand.

Comment: @Barmar `pointData.byteLength` is 519820 as visible in the screenshot, was matters (and what was already the culprit in the previous question) is `pointData.buffer.byteLength`

Comment: And what is the bytelength of the buffer? I mistakenly assumed that they would be the same.

Comment: @Bergi, for int8 arrays `buffer.bytelength` and `.length` are equals, `Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` is `1` and `519820` is divisible by 4. So no, the error isn't really clear, *if we assume that it came from the line after the call to `console.log`*. But certainly it's not from there, since the source of the log are from different files, *deck.js* must be using another object.

Comment: OP, can you activate "Pause on uncaught exceptions" in your dev-tools's "Sources" tab? And then check in the *Scope* sub panel what object has been passed, and walking up the *Call Stack* one to find from where it came?

Comment: @Kaiido Only if the typed array is a view on the entire buffer, but it might be a slice (with offset and smaller length). This actually appears to be the case here, as seen in the console output [on their previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76624160/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi oh `subarray()`! (not `slice`), right, I forgot about that.

Comment: But then aren't both questions actually the same? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624160/type-conversion-from-uint8array-to-float32

Comment: @Kaiido [I certainly think so](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77267800/timeline#history_f7d8250d-6e9c-4ff2-bd59-788ccf91b5a0) but will wait for a reaction from the OP before closing it again…